# Passing pyplot points as arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

So I initialised a pyplot figure

```
import ... ## import all relevent modules

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3),dpi(100)
a = plt.subplot(111)
a.set_xlim(left=0,right=25,auto=False)
a.set_ylim(bottom=0,top=250,auto=False)

a.plot([5,10,15],[80,150,210])
plt.show()
```

This works fine... What I want to be able to do is to write a function that can update the scatter plot dynamically... Something like:

```
def plot_point(x_coord,y_coord):
  a.plot([x_coord],[y_coord])
  a.draw() ## I thought this would work... :(
```

No error, but the point doesn't get plotted. How can I get around this? The reason I've done it using figures is so I can embed it in Tkinter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You say "scatter plot" but you're using .plot(), not .scatter(); do you want a line that's updated or a new point on a scatter plot?

Comment: New point on a scatter plot. Let me try using scatter() not plot()

Comment: It works! Thank you DSM! Such a small issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

`plot` is perfectly fine to use for plotting individual points (it is even recommend over `scatter`, if you don't wanna add additional information through color or size of the dots). What is missing in the initial example is setting the right linestyle; obviously, a line consisting of a single point doesn't show up. Changing the line style to '+' or something similar fixes the problem:

```
def plot_point(x_coord,y_coord):
  a.plot([x_coord],[y_coord], '+')
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between `plot` and `scatter` and +1 (if I could) for explaining why a line of a single point doesn't display, and how to fix that...